# SAML authentication with NextJs

Tags: next.js, saml, next-auth

I need to manage authentication in a NextJs 14 project with app folder.
We have Single Sign On in our organization with a SAML IDP, I can't find information about how to add SAML authentication on NextJs with app folder.

Anyone can help us?

I followed this guide but is for the old structure of NodeJs and I can't adapt it
https://dev.to/nathan_tarbert/saml-sso-the-missing-piece-in-your-nextjs-apps-authentication-puzzle-3h9f